# How do I get the "NEW" Stack Overflow button back?

Tags: support

I was checking out the new teams feature for Stack Overflow. I closed the X in the corner, and the <kbd>NEW</kbd> button disappeared from the header.

How can I get the <kbd>NEW</kbd> button back?

Comment: It just goes to the [Teams Page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).

Comment: It's not new anymore, you've already seen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete the "notice-sot" cookie.

Comment: In the current version of Firefox it is menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Privacy & Security* → section "History", "remove individual cookies" → site "stackoverflow.com" → select "stackoverflow.com notice-sot" → press button "Remove Selected" → press button "Close".

Comment: However, it didn't make any difference for me (also restarting Firefox and opening new pages that were never opened before).